# Mobile Usability: Need help fixing "Text too small..." and "Clickable elements too close..."

Tags: html, css

I have created a website on this domain bullrundistributor.com using simple HTML and **inline CSS** as I am only a newbie in this whole thing. The webpages accessible from the menu look good on the desktop, but nowhere near ideal on mobile and tablets. I have tried some responsive page creation recommendations on W3Schools, but I am still not sure why I am getting these errors on my Google Console Mobile Usability page:

- Text too small to read
- Clickable elements too close together

I would very much appreciate someone's help with this as it is just making me miserable after so many trials and failures.

As I am a newbie, please let me know what more information I should be sharing regarding this issue.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS code so it's easier for other developers to help you.

Comment: Dear Filip, thanks for your response. I couldn't paste my code here. If you would please visit http://bullrundistributor.com/index.php and view page source there, everything is there (both CSS style and HTML)

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. Google tells you exactly where the problem is BRW so read the report in the console and fix it yourself  - We can't guess your code

Comment: Thank you dear Alon, but I don't know how to pinpoint the problem on the Google Console page. Sorry I must sound like an idiot :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
2. use media queries and write the max width of the screen to have the style

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
     div { 
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

- or you can use bootstrap
- if you want some more help you can provide some pieces of your code and images for the error

Comment: Dear zxc, I have used the viewport you have posted.

Comment: For number two, please check the source code of my page as it has both CSS and HTML.

Comment: - sorry i haven't any other thing to help you .. - you should provide a simple example for your code gives the same error to help you better

Comment: dear zxc, I tried to paste the whole code of my page (which is relatively short) here with no luck. I hope I can have some help with that too. Sorry :(

Comment: - Look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
to know how to markdown your question and post your code..  
in most block code placed between 3 Grave Accent like this   
\```  
//Code here    
\```
- if your code isn't formatted - reformat your code from [this link](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html) to make it easy to read, maintain and try to make the format 4 spaces look at the guide to know why + if you want to post the whole page no problem but it's will be better if you created a simple example which can show the error and explain the error part well

Comment: That's awfully helpful. Thank you very much indeed. @zxc vpn